# Pytest Mock AWS SecurityManager

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, aws-secrets-manager

my project has a file called config.py which has, among others, the following code:

```
class Secret(Enum):
    DATABASE_A = 'name_of_secret_database_A'
    DATABASE_A = 'name_of_secret_database_A'

    def secret(self):
        if self.value:
            return get_secret(self.value)
        return {}

def get_secret(secret_name):
    session = Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name='us-east-1',
    )
    secret_value = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    return loads(secret_value.get('SecretString', "{}"))
```

I need to somehow mock **get_secret** in tests with pytest for all enum calls, for example *Secret.DATABASE_A.secret ()*

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `monkeypatch` to override the behaviour of `get_secret()`. I have made the `get_secret()` method a static method of the Secret class, but you can make it part of any module you want and import it as well. Just make sure you change in in the `monkeypatch.setattr()` call as well.

```
import pytest
from enum import Enum


class Secret(Enum):
    DATABASE_A = 'name_of_secret_database_A'
    DATABASE_B = 'name_of_secret_database_B'

    def secret(self):
        if self.value:
            return Secret.get_secret(self.value)
        return {}
        
    @staticmethod
    def get_secret(secret_name):
        session = Session()
        client = session.client(
            service_name='secretsmanager',
            region_name='us-east-1',
        )
        secret_value = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
        return loads(secret_value.get('SecretString', "{}"))

def test_secret_method(monkeypatch):
    def get_secret(secret_name):
        return "supersecret"
    
    monkeypatch.setattr(Secret, "get_secret", get_secret)

    s = Secret.DATABASE_A
    assert s.secret() == "supersecret"
```

This returns into 1 passed test.

What is happening here is, that I created a function `get_secret()` in my test_secret_method as well, and then overwrite the `Secret.get_secret()` with that new method. Now, you can use the Secret class in your test_method and be sure what the 'get_secret()' method will return without actually running the original code.